# setfacl remove group permission

Tags: linux, unix, system

I am trying to remove group ACL from a certain folder. It has permissions as below

```
$ getfacl --all-effective public
# file: public
# owner: sse02
# group: apache
user::rwx
group::r-x                      #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x              #effective:r-x
default:group:acct:rwx     #effective:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
$
```

I wanted to remove the access granted to the group 'acct' with the following command, but it is not simply working

```
setfacl -x g:acct public
```

What could be going on wrong? Any ideas?

This is a RHEL5 box with ext3 file system.

Answer (score 7):

The `group:acct` entry is listed with `default:` in front, and the `setfacl` man page suggests that the ACL specification can be (spaces added for clarity in the man page):

> ```
> [d[efault]:] g[roup]:gid [:perms]
> ```
>
> Permissions of a named group. Permissions of the owning group if gid is empty.

I think you should try:

```
setfacl -x d:g:acct public
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 setfacl -Rm g::--- diectoryname
```

Comment: Please add some details

Answer (score 0):

According to https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl using -k will remove default ACL permissions.

Here is a sample of how I just removed defaults from a directory:

```
SSH: getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: docker
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x

00:01:42
SSH: sudo setfacl -k .
00:01:45
SSH: getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: docker
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, to remove the group `GROUP` ACL entries for the `DIRECTORY` use:

```
setfacl -x g:GROUP DIRECTORY
```

To completely remove all ACL entries use:

```
setfacl -b DIRECTORY
```

Add `-R` option to make the actions **recursive**

**Options** *(from the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl))*

> **-R, --recursive** - Apply operations to all files and directories recursively.
>
> **-x (--remove)** and -X (--remove-file) options remove ACL entries. It is not an error to remove an entry which does not exist.
>
> **-b, --remove-all** - Remove all extended ACL entries. The base ACL entries of the owner, group and others are retained.

**Note:** to get the ACL list use

```
getfacl DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
setfacl -d -x g:acct public
```

Comment: Please explain why your solution is better than the one in the other answers.